# Drupal Background Photo

Tags: image, css, drupal-7, directory, background-image

This is the site: http://www.rybm.org/

There is supposed to be a full background called bg.jpg. It displays perfectly on my local xammp run Drupal 7 install, but will not work on the live site.

It is declared in the styles.css body tag, just like this: background-image:url('wo77crop.jpg');

Any ideas on why it would display correctly on the local install, but not the server? I put the image in the same folder (css) as the stylesheet I dbeclared it on, just to be absolutely certain it wasn't happening because I was pointing to the wrong directory. So, the image is in the CSS folder, along with the stylesheet.

I'm still wondering if it's not a directory issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That image is pointing to http://www.rybm.org/sites/all/themes/skeletontheme/css/bg.jpg as you just use:

```
background-image: url('bg.jpg');
```

and the CSS file specifying it is in the CSS directory. Without knowing where you saved the image, I can't tell you exactly what the path should be. If it was in an images folder at the same level as your css folder, you'd do:

```
background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks. I sorted it out. It wasn't the filepath, but the image file, itself. I was a little too quick pulling the trigger on this one. I appreciate it!!!